No communication with remote language server with lsp-mode and tramp?
I'm trying to use lsp-mode for files on a remote server (a container in a kubernetes cluster). According to the documentation it should work automagically but I do not get it to work.
The relevant configuration in my .spacemacs file looks as following:
   ...
   ...
   dotspacemacs-configuration-layers
   '(...
     ...
     lsp
     (python :variables
             python-backend 'lsp
             python-lsp-server 'pylsp)
     ...
     ...

When I open a remote file (over tramp/ssh) I see that the language server is started on the remote host. The (relevant) output of ps -aux looks as following. I.e. these are the processes that have been started by lsp-mode/tramp:
root         598  0.0  0.0   3056   916 pts/2    Ss+  19:36   0:00 cat /tmp/tramp.mqMuG9
root         606  0.0  0.0   2588   912 pts/3    Ss+  19:36   0:00 /bin/sh -c stty raw > /dev/null; pylsp
root         616 12.8  0.2 430012 80564 pts/3    Sl+  19:36   0:01 /usr/local/bin/python3.11 /usr/local/bin/pylsp

However, in the modeline in emacs I keep seeing LSP[pylsp-tramp:8241/starting]. And in the *lsp-log: pylsp-tramp:8241* buffer I only see the
Sending request 'initialize - (19)'.
message (including it's content). But I do not see any answer coming back from the server.
Does anyone have an idea what could be going wrong here? What next step(s) could I take to troubleshoot/find out why no answer is coming back from the remote language-server?

Per my understanding, the server answer should go to stdout. So you can try running it manually and sending it text, and see whether it replies or doesn't. You may also find useful seeing the processes being run with their args via sudo bpftrace -e 'tracepoint:syscalls:sys_enter_exec*{ printf("pid: %d, comm: %s, args: ", pid, comm); join(args->argv); }'.
